# Error al mostrar el resultado de sentencia sql

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

Mi error consta de que tengo una tabla donde muestro info de usuarios de un paginador, mi error consta que tengo una consulta SQL que el resultado se manda a una función que me pinta mi tabla en una variable  PHP recorro mi resultado con foreach en php y me lo pinta bien la primera vez  , pero cuando damos click a otra pagina de paginador al pintar y usar la misma funcion para recorrer la misma consulta que ya estaba pintada me aparece undefined pero solo en el alias de nombre y puesto y si muestro en las 3 columnas el puro id si lo muestra
No tengo idea que me pueda estar afectanto , si es en mi consulta o alguna otra cosa

Esta es mi consulta:

```
public static function mostrarUser(){
 $conex=MetodoMartin::Conexion();
        $sqli = "SELECT PE.id AS id ,CONCAT(usuarios.nombre,' ',paterno,' ',materno) AS nombre , P.nombre AS puesto, S.nombre AS sucursal,D.nombre AS departamento FROM usuarios 
                        INNER JOIN puestos AS P ON P.id_puesto= usuarios.id_puesto 
                        INNER JOIN permisos AS PE ON PE.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuario 
                        INNER JOIN sucursales AS S ON S.id_sucursal = usuarios.id_sucursal 
                        INNER JOIN departamentos AS D ON D.id_departamento = usuarios.id_departamento 
                        WHERE usuarios.situacion='1' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,30";
        $result = mysqli_query($conex,$sqli);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
        return $data;
}
```

esta es mi funcion de php donde inserto y retorno mi variable en una tabla

```
public static function mostrarPermisos(){
        $html='';
        $colorFila= true;
        $respuesta = permisosModel::mostrarUser()
      
        foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item) {
            $html.='<div class="divContenedorPadre renglon'.(boolval($colorFila=!$colorFila) ? 1 : 0).'">
                        <div class="encabezadoNumero"><b>'.$item["id"].'</b></div>
                        <div class="encabezadoNombre" style="justify-content: flex-start;">'.$item["nombre"].'</div>      
                        <div class="encabezadoPuesto" style="justify-content: flex-start;">'.$item["puesto"].'</div>
                        
                        <div class="encabezadoPermisos " style="justify-content: flex-start;"><a class="btn btn-success mostrarPermisos mostrar" href="#modal_permisos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_permisos" id="permisos_form">Mostrar</a></div>
                    </div>';
        }
        
        return $html;
    }
```

este es mi controlador donde retorno mi variable Para mandarla a javascript y que posteriormente la pinta

```
public function paginador(){
         
         $data = PermisosControllers::mostrarPermisos();
         echo json_encode(array("html"=>$data));
    
  }
```

este mi archivo js donde obtengo la variable y la muestro en donde se debe

```
static recargarPaginador(datos){
  Permisos.dataPrincipal.html('<div style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-pulse fa-fw" style="font-size:110px;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;color:#3489df;"></i></div>');
    MetodosDiversos.consultaAjaxFormulario("controllers/AjaxPermisos.php", datos,(respuesta)=>{
      
        document.getElementById("dataPermisosUser").innerHTML=respuesta.html;
        
    });
}
```

Pero el resultado es undefined. pero si en mi archivo donde inserto y retorno mi variable en una tabla en vez de id nombre y los 3 los remplasamos por id si pinta la ntabla de otra forma me sale undefined

Comment: De entrada, no tienes un paginador como tal, siempre obtienes las primeras 30 filas con `LIMIT 0,30` en la consulta. Luego, la pregunta no está del todo clara, por favor edita para explicar dónde recibes el `undefined` (Javascript o PHP) y cómo es que tratas de cargar datos de otra página, tanto en Javascript como en PHP.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu observación.  Como dice  noes un paginador como tal por que el limite es 30 siempre seran los primeros 30 y si quiero mostrar lo mismo 30 que haga función como un paginador  , pero el problema es al recorrer la consulta por 2 vez con las mismas funciones , la variable  que retorno desde php la imprimo con javascript , pero el udefined viene PHP al volver a recorrer otra vez la misma respuesta con for each al llegar al $item["nombre"] mada undefined

Comment: Repito: Edita la pregunta para agregar los códigos involucrados (Javascript y PHP) con los que intentas mostrar otra página, de lo contrario, no es posible tratar de ayudarte a identificar dónde está el error.